# Inject services in class instance in Angular

Tags: angular

I tried to use instance of class inside class static property:

```
class MyHelper {
  private authService: AuthService;

  constructor() {
    this.authService = inject(AuthService);    
    this.user = this.authService.getUser();    
  }

  private static get instance(): MyHelper {
    return new MyHelper();
  }
}
```

And I get an Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: inject() must be called from an injection context.

I tried variant as below (there is same result):

```
class MyHelper {
    private authService = inject(AuthService);
    
    constructor() {          
      this.user = this.authService.getUser();    
    }
    
    private static get instance(): MyHelper {
      return new MyHelper();
    }
  }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to move `inject()` to outside of the constructor, and define it as a class member

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix the singleton pattern (`getInstance`) with the Dependency injection.

`inject()` requires an [injection context](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context).

Make your helper class an injectable service.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class MyHelper {
...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't or I can't do it even if I wish it too much?

Comment: You'd have to call it with `runInInjectionContext()` every time you call `MyHelper .instance()`

Comment: The singleton is mostly a bad practice (with a few exceptions only). You should really avoid it if you can